# CheckGenesis use case(s)

Tags: substrate

In today's Substrate Collaborative Learning, the *SignedExtension* impl for *CheckGenesis* came up (see [this riot conversation](https://matrix.to/#/!HzySYSaIhtyWrwiwEV:matrix.org/$157167794745952DfEuO:matrix.parity.io?via=matrix.parity.io&via=matrix.org&via=web3.foundation) for validation-related discussion).
Going back to first principles, what are the use case(s) for *CheckGenesis* ?

Answer (score 0):

When a user submits a transaction to a Substrate-based blockchain, there is extra signed data attached to the transaction to ensure it is applied to the correct chain state that the user intended it for. You can see what kind of additional signed data is attached in the [node template](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b9d66637857017356983dd021c1d200898561eb7/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L275-L282)

The purpose of `CheckGenesis` is to ensure that the transaction is submitted to the correct chain instead of a different one. Without `CheckGenesis`, the following attack would be possible.

Alice pays Bob a few tokens on a chain that they both commonly use.
The transaction goes through as expected and Bob receives the tokens.
Bob notices that Alice re-uses her key on another chain.
So he submits her transaction to that second chain as well.
The transaction also goes through on the second chain, and Bob receives a second payment.

By referring to the chain that the transaction is intended for in the signed data, Alice can prevent that attack.

As cryptographic advice, you should not reuse keys across applications in general. Not all blockchains are based on Substrate, and not all chains include this check.